# Does an OS lock the entire amount of ram inside your computer

Tags: c++, memory-management

I was wondering if for example. *Windows* completely lock all the available ram so that some really bored person with too much time on their hands cannot start deleting memory from another process (somehow).

The question originated from what was happening when using the `delete` function in C++ (was C++ telling the OS that the OS can now release the memory for overwriting or was C++ telling the hardware to unlock the memory)... and then spawned on to me thinking of specific hardware created to interface with the RAM at hardware level and start deleting memory chunks for the fun of it. ie a hacker perhaps.

***My thoughts were:*** The *Windows* memory management program is told memory is free to be written to again, right? But does that also mean that the memory address is still set to locked at a hardware level so that the memory can only be taken control of by *windows* rather than another OS. Or is it like the wild west down at hardware level... If *Windows* isn't locking memory, anything else can use the part that is now free.

I guess the real question is, is there a hardware level lock on memory addresses that operating systems can trigger... so that the memory has locked itself down and cannot be re-assigned then?

Comment: In Windows terminology, locking memory means the memory is not pageable.

Comment: How do you "mark memory for deletion" in C++?  C++ is not garbage collected - you delete it it is returned to the heap.

Comment: Ah, my bad terminology

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 :  I am a dinosaur embedded systems developer - a domain where C++99 is still struggling to gain acceptance, and C++11 hardly figures, to the extent I have mostly ignored it.  That said as I understand it, smart-pointers are not the same as garbage collection, but a different solution to the same (or similar) problem.  Moreover they are implemented in the library rather thean built in to the language.

Comment: @Clifford: What is "C++99"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Indeed:  C++98.

Comment: @Clifford: So in your localised domain (N.B. I'm an embedded systems developer and can say with authority that this certainly is not the case for the _entire_ embedded world) everyone's still writing pre-standard C++?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : No I mean C++ gaining acceptance over C; I mentioned C++98 specifically to distinguish it from C++11 in my other point about it not having smart-pointers.  *C* remains prevalent in small memory embedded systems, running bare-metal, or RTOS kernel rather then Linux (spits),  and there is some resistance to C++ in general (evidenced by the issues I have recruiting experienced embedded C++ staff).  Outside of GCC most compilers support ISO C++98.  IAR's compilers only support the ill-considered and largely obsolete EC++ subset.

Comment: @Clifford: Oh right, okay. Yes, if we're talking the C->C++ path (rather than the pre-standard C++ -> standard C++ -> modern C++ path) then I'd agree with that of course. Your having [almost ;p] named C++ **98** specifically confused me as to what you were claiming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76703/discussion-between-clifford-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: @Clifford: Dunno, think we're done! :)

Comment: Indded; my final remark was way off topic that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if Windows completely lock all the available ram

Windows, like any other operating system, uses all the available RAM.

> so that some really bored person with too much time on their hands cannot start deleting memory from another process (somehow).

*Non sequitur.* It does it because that's what it's supposed to do. It's an operating system, and it is supposed to control all the hardware resources.

> The question originated from what was happening when you mark memory for deletion in C++.

I don't know what 'mark memory for deletion in C++' means, but if you refer to the `delete` operator, or the `free()` function, they in general do not release memory to the operating system.

> My thoughts were: The Windows memory management program is told memory is free to be written to again, right?

Wrong, see above.

> But does that also mean that the memory address is still set to locked at a hardware level so that the memory can only be taken control of by windows rather than another OS.

What other OS? Unless you're in a virtual environment, there is no other OS, and even if you are, the virtual environment hands control over all the designated RAM to the guest operating system.

> Or is it like the wild west down at hardware level... If Windows isn't locking memory, anything else can use the part that is now free.

Anything else such as?

> I guess the real question is, is there a hardware level lock on memory addresses that operating systems can trigger?

In general yes, there are hardware definitions of what privilege level is required to access each memory segment. For example, the operating system's own memory is immune to appliucation processes, and application processes are immune to each other: but this is all highly hardware-dependent.

Your question doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: This is uber helpful man. Thanks... I think my question must have made sense if you answered so spot on. Thank you so much! #virtualbeero !

In response to the "Anything else such as", I was thinking of some kind of hardware made by a  hacker that is literally attached (in some magical way) to the ram and thus now has complete control over memory allocation... I was wondering if there was some hardware security... Looks like you've said yes.. re privileges part.

Comment: _"they in general do not release memory to the operating system"_ True, the runtime can keep the memory hoarded for later use. But that leads me to believe that this is _not_ what the OP means by "mark memory for deletion". If we take that to mean an utterance of `free()` that, for whatever reason, _does_ result in actual freeing at the lowest-level, then of course Windows can do whatever it wants with that memory afterwards. Then again, it can _always_ do whatever it wants with that memory. The whole question is pretty vacuous.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Your question was about Windows, not special hardware. If you're thinking of a specific attack mode you should have mentioned it in your question. Once you have dedicated hardware, anything can happen.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit I have no idea what the OP meant by that, and he hasn't bothered to clarify it. Mere speculation is pointless.

Comment: @EJP: I did precisely the same amount of speculation as you did in your answer!

Comment: EJP, Lightning Racis in Orbit, my apologies dudes... I've clarified the question more for newcomers. Thanks for your uber awesome help buddovskies!

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 So what *do* you mean by 'delete memory using C++'?

Comment: @EJP "The question originated from what was happening when using the delete function in C++" <- surely he means this ?

Comment: @user2808054 When I answered the question it contained the text that I quoted. The text you quote was edited in later. The revision history shows it clearly.

Answer (score 3):

The concept you're looking for is *mapping*, not *locking.

The memory is just *there*. The OS does nothing special about that.

What it *does* is map chunks of it into individual processes. Each process can see only the memory that is mapped into its address space. Trying to access any other address just leads to an access violation (or segmentation fault on Unixes). There's just nothing at those addresses. Not "locked memory", just *nothing*.

And when the OS decides to (or when the process requests it), a page of memory can be unmapped from a given process again.

It's not locking though. The memory isn't "owned" by the process it is mapped to. And the same memory can be mapped into the address spaces of multiple processes at the same time. That's one way to exchange data between processes.

So the OS doesn't "lock" or control ownership of memory. It just controls whether a given chunk of memory is visible to any particular process.

Answer (score 1):

It is not as simple as that, also Windows is not open-source, so exactly what it does may not be published.  However all addresses in user space code are virtual and MMU protected - address X in one process does not refer to the same physical memory as address X in another, and one process cannot access that of another.  An attempt to access memory outside of the address space of a process will cause an MMU exception.

I believe that when Windows starts a process, it has an initial heap allocation, from which dynamic memory allocation occurs.  Deleting a dynamically allocated block simply returns it to the process's existing heap (not to the OS).  If the current heap has insufficient memory, additional memory is requested from the OS to expand it.

Memory can be shared between processes in a controlled manner - in Windows this is done via a memory-mapped file, and uses the same virtual-memory mechanisms as the swap-file uses to emulate more memory that is physically available.

I think rather than asking a question on SO for this you'd do better to first do a little basic research, start at [About Memory Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366525%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN for example.

With respect to external hardware accessing the memory it is possible to implement shared memory between processors (it is not that uncommon; for example see [here](http://kumanov.com/docs/prog/VxWorks/vxworks/netguide/c-dll5.html) for example), but it is not a matter of "wild-west" the mechanisms for doing so are implemented via the OS.

Even on conventional PC architectures, many devices access memory directly via [DMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) as a method of performing I/O without CPU overhead. Again this is controlled by the OS and not at all "wild west", but an errant device driver could bring down your system - which is why Microsoft have a testing and approvals process for drivers.

Comment: Ahhhh! Excellent... Thanks for the link too, going to eat that up at lunch... Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.
RAM is managed by software, RAM can't lock itself.

Comment: Edited the last part of my question. Thanks though!

Comment: The answer stays the same. The software manages the memory. If the OS is the real OS (not running on Virtual machine), it can lock memory by not allowing other software editing or viewing that part of memory.
But like any software, it can have bugs, faults, etc., allowing other software to access this.
(That's where Windows Update comes in ;-) )

Comment: So if someone was to create some amazing hardware that attached to the memory at hardware level... it too could now control memory allocation and could literally read the memory, mark memory for deletion etc...

Comment: Yes, that should be possible.

Comment: WOW! Thanks PSVSupporter... That's pretty much what this question was about!

Comment: That's not "amazing hardware"; on a PC I/O devices regularly use *direct memory access* (DMA), and  outside of regular PC architecture there are shared-memory backplane architecture systems.  However if such a system were to arbitrarily access memory without coordination with other bus masters - that wouldn''t be "amazing" it would be a recipe for system failure.

Comment: Hahah, worded like poetry. Thanks for that info, extremely helpful man.

Answer (score 0):

You asked the wrong question. There is no such thing as a hardware lock on memory. The trick is [virtual memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) which makes only controlled amounts of memory available to a process. The OS controls all available memory, that's its job, and processes only ever see the memory that the OS has given to them.